# UITabBarItem Change Image Height and Width

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarItem without a title and only an image. I was wondering how I can change the image size so it can take up the whole UITabBarItem.

I searched all over the internet but found nothing.

I tried:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tab"];
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, -6, -10);
```

but nothing changed.

Thank you!

Comment: @llario Still does not work

Comment: let me see your modified code

Comment: @llario Just edited question

Comment: ok but you should set the TabBar as RootViewController as I wrote in the code I posted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from apple documentation the maximum size of a picture on the TabBar are 30x30 (60x60 for the retina display).

I do not think it's possible to take the entire height of the TabBar without strecth the image. I think the best solution is to center the image in the TabBar using imageInset

```
tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```

[image]

otherwise you can play with this imageInset and strecth the image like in the screenshot

```
tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, -6, -10);
```

[image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {


 UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

 UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

 //add image to tabbarItems

 tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -10, -6, -10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer..now my app gets really nice look :)

Comment: @Android_kalai Happy to have helped ;-)

Comment: Hey, click twice on image. It scales :S

Comment: Did you find a solution for the scaling of image when clicked twice?