# tabbar icons stretching in UITabbar

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have tabbar icon size of 30x30. When i set these icons to tabbar, images are stretching for iphone4 & iphone5 screen sizes. Why?

```
UINavigationController *hndWriteNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hndWrite];  
        hndWriteNav.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browse.png"];

        [hndWriteNav setTitle:@"Browse"];
        [hndWrite release];
```

Comment: Use Retina image(60*60) with name **@2x** appending to image name.

Comment: You mean Browse@2x.png?

Comment: You want to use UIEdgeInsets as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499356/uitabbaritem-change-image-height-and-width).

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two separate icons **browse.png (30x30)** and **browse@2x.png (60x60)**.

iOS will automatically load the right file based on the screen scale.

Comment: I have these 2 files.  But i used browse.png.

Comment: It's not working. If i use browse@2x.png, the images are not showing in tabbar.

Comment: than make sure your are using currect images. i guess there is problem in images.